# MAC: Mono Helloworld example

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I did a fresh install of Mono on my OSX Yosemite and tried the examples on http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/.

The Console Hello World example runs without problem but when I tried the WindowsForm Hello World, I got the following error :

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GdipCreateFromContext_macosx at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdipCreateFromContext_macosx (intptr,int,int,intptr&)
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd (IntPtr hwnd) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUICarbon.PaintEventStart (System.Windows.Forms.Message& msg, IntPtr handle, Boolean client) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.PaintEventStart (System.Windows.Forms.Message& msg, IntPtr handle, Boolean client) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Chads-MacBook-Pro:C# ChadLeong$ mono hello.exe
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GdipCreateFromContext_macosx
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdipCreateFromContext_macosx (intptr,int,int,intptr&)
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd (IntPtr hwnd) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUICarbon.PaintEventStart (System.Windows.Forms.Message& msg, IntPtr handle, Boolean client) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.PaintEventStart (System.Windows.Forms.Message& msg, IntPtr handle, Boolean client) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Anyone got a clue ? Thank you!!

Comment: Sounds like you have no entry point, such as `Main` in C# console program.

Comment: Hmmm, but I was merely following the instruction on the tutorial for "WindowsForm  Hello World": http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/. 

It should still compile right?

Comment: The example in the page you just posted contains this method block: static public void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");
    }

Without that main method, it will not compile.

Comment: @furkle its the next example. "WindowsForm Hello World".. The code should look like this using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class HelloWorld : Form
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Application.Run (new HelloWorld ());
    }

    public HelloWorld ()
    {
        Text = "Hello Mono World";
    }
}

Comment: But you must see the `Main` you just typed. Anyway, if that's the way yours looks then there seems to be something else. Reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.entrypointnotfoundexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a start.

Comment: that's not helping because I'm using mac. Anyone else has ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known bug/regression in the 3.10 release: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23553

This Xamarin forum thread provides a version with a fix: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27011/fix-for-gdipcreatefromcontext-macosx-and-other-macios-gdi-issues

Comment: Thanks this is a legit answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Wow. Two weeks later and they are STILL distributing a known broken MDK? and it was fixed two weeks ago! I'm happy it is fixed, but I am annoyed that I wasted an hour of my life before I found this post.

Comment: I know right ! I spent so much time figuring it out and made bug post (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24205). It is fixed now but not released yet.