# WinForms Application window closes immediately on open in OSX

Tags: c#, winforms, macos, mono

I've been developing WinForms applications in C# for Windows for years.

Today I tried to port a very simple project of mine over but whenever the application starts the main window opens and immediately closes.
I broke it down to just a simple form.

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
     public TestForm()
     {
         InitializeComponent();            
     }
}
```

with a main like so:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new TestForm());
}
```

Anyway as soon as I run the application the Window flashes open and immediately closes and of course closing the app. I'm using Mono 3.1 and Xamarin Studio 5.5.3. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does your example here have the same issue? If not, then we need to see more information like your Form Load, etc.

Comment: Yes. This example has the same issue.

Comment: You may be running into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667656/mac-mono-helloworld-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alexander's comment the answer to the post: [MAC: Mono Helloworld example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667656/mac-mono-helloworld-example)
was what I needed. It is apparently a bug in Mono MDK 3.1.0.
Downloading and installing the linked update from dropbox fixed it!

Thanks all!